# What is the initiating actor for the usecase shown here

Tags: uml, use-case

I am new to drawing use case and writing use case descriptions.

I have an Actor called `User` , an abstract usecase called `Work Type` and another use case called `Manager`. The usecase `Manager` has a generalized relationship with the `Work Type` use case.

I'm now writing the use case description for `Manager` use case. And what is the initiating Actor for this use case. Is it the Actor `User` ? or doesn't it have an initiating Actor ?

Note: I only want to know the initiating Actor for the use case `Manager`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel, you will be the best person to decide that with the use cases you are describing. For deciding the actors you should find out who is external and is interacting with the use case manager, based on the context of the use case you are describing

Answer (score 0):

The actor "User" is inherited by the "Manager" Usecase. You could add another or different Actor e.g. "ManagerUser" and derive this from "User" if you'd like to point out that the Actor for the Manager UseCase differs from User. You'd have to think about what discriminates/distinguishes this other Actor from the base Actor "User".